# Regroup data before sum

Tags: sql

I'm a beginner with SQL Queries but I made this simple query which output the following data:

```
select ID, Length, Weight
from MyTable
where Group in('A1', 'A2')
```

[image]

What I would like to do is to group the lines by ID and Length and then only sum of all the data in the Weight column.

So basically I would get :

| ID | Length | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,635 | 2,2 |
| 1 | 2,935 | 43,8 |
| 2 | 2,305 | 1 |
| 2 | 2,935 | 45 |
| 3 | 0,281 | 0,1 |
| 3 | 0,443 | 0,2 |
| 3 | 0,604 | 0,3 |

and then return the sum of the weight column.

This sounds simple but I can't manage to make it work...

Any Idea ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`, and `SUM()`.

Comment: A bit hard to read the input data, but lenght 0,604 mean 0.604 in your description, right?

Comment: Fyi, it's `Length` not `Lenght`

Answer (score 1):

Assume lenght 0,604 mean 0.604 in your problem description, a [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator and [sum()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_sum.asp) function should be able to get what your want, and then use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to all weight sum added to each line.

See the following code as an example:

```
select ID, Lenght, 
sum(Weight) as toal_weight_per_line,
SUM(SUM(weight)) OVER() as all_weight
from record
GROUP BY ID, Lenght
ORDER BY ID, Lenght
```

[VERIFIED RUNNING EXAMPLE SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6ecc16/12)

| ID | Lenght | toal_weight_per_line | all_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.635 | 2.2 | 92.6 |
| 1 | 2.935 | 43.8 | 92.6 |
| 2 | 2.305 | 1 | 92.6 |
| 2 | 2.935 | 45 | 92.6 |
| 3 | 0.281 | 0.1 | 92.6 |
| 3 | 0.443 | 0.2 | 92.6 |
| 3 | 0.604 | 0.3 | 92.6 |

Another method is to use [CROSS JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_cross.asp) operator

See the following code as example:

```
SELECT
    per_line.ID,
    per_line.Lenght,
    per_line.toal_weight_per_line,
    total.all_weight
FROM
(
    select ID, Lenght, 
    sum(Weight) as toal_weight_per_line
    from record
    GROUP BY ID, Lenght
) per_line
cross join
(
    select sum(weight) as all_weight
    FROM
    record
) total
ORDER BY ID, Lenght
```

[VERIFIED RUNNING EXAMPLE SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6ecc16/16)

| ID | Lenght | toal_weight_per_line | all_weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.635 | 2.2 | 92.6 |
| 1 | 2.935 | 43.8 | 92.6 |
| 2 | 2.305 | 1 | 92.6 |
| 2 | 2.935 | 45 | 92.6 |
| 3 | 0.281 | 0.1 | 92.6 |
| 3 | 0.443 | 0.2 | 92.6 |
| 3 | 0.604 | 0.3 | 92.6 |

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. Yes 0,604 mean 0.604. 
Would it be possible to display only the total Weight sum instead of all the lines? 92.6 in our example.

Comment: Hi @Wehrmicel, you can use windon function to add all weight sum. I have updated my query example link to also add all weight sum to each line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
Sadly it seems that "OVER()" does not work with the SQL version of the software I use. it's probably too old or too limited. I will have to find another solution. Thanks again and have a nice day

Comment: HI @Wehrmicel, I add another method to use cross join operator instead of window function. Have a try to see whether it works for your system.

Comment: Still no luck with cross join.
I don't think the software was designed to handle this kind of complex queries.
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your problem?

```sql
SELECT ID, Length, SUM(Weight) AS TotalWeight
FROM MyTable
WHERE Group IN ('A1', 'A2')
GROUP BY ID, Length
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.

I actually managed to use the group by ID and Length. It groups the rows well as desired.

However I would like to return the final sum of the whole Weight column after the grouping. Is it possible to do this in the same query?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to return the sum of the Weight column in the same query

Comment: can you explain to me please ? this is the part of the query that I don't know how to do